# Convert command cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I've never done any curl before so am in need of some help. I've tried to work this out from examples but cannot get my head around it!

How can I translate this curl command so that it works in a PHP script?

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --cert WST279925._.1.pem --key WST279925._.1.key --pass fryeBu23^< -u WST279925._.1:KaWwNI31=$ --url https://test.ipg-online.com/ipgapi/services -d @request.xml --trace-ascii "trace.log" -o "response.xml" --insecure
```

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.ipg-online.com/ipgapi/services');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array(
    'file' => '@' .realpath('request.xml')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'WST279925._.1' . ':' . $_ENV["KaWwNI31="]);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/xml';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

how do i add digital certificate and key?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What kind of issues are you having? Please elaborate on what your attempts are actually producing and any associated code. My guess is you're not escaping special characters before they hit the command line.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

See **CURLOPT_SSLCERT** and **CURLOPT_SSLKEY**